# Solver(ipopt) did not exit normally - python/jupyter/ubuntu

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, ipopt

I am trying to solve `pyomo` model using python and jupyter notebook on ubuntu. To solve this, I am using a solver called "`Ipopt`" because my problem is non-linear. But it is giving me this error everytime. I have tried everything but it is not resolving.

```
ERROR: Solver (ipopt) returned non-zero return code (-11)
ERROR: See the solver log above for diagnostic information.
```

---

## ApplicationError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-76-287a30c5476c> in <module> 
      
          3 opt = SolverFactory('ipopt',executable='/usr/local/bin/ipopt')

    ----> 4 results = opt.solve(model,tee=True)
    

     ~/project/my_project_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py in solve(self, *args, **kwds)
    598                     logger.error("Solver log:\n" + str(_status.log))
    599                 raise pyutilib.common.ApplicationError(
    --> 600                     "Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name)
    601             solve_completion_time = time.time()
    602             if self._report_timing:

    ApplicationError: Solver (ipopt) did not exit normally
```

From where I can check solver log ?? or is there any other solver for non-linear problem which can be done with `pyomo` ??

Answer (score 2):

After checking possible [IPOPT options](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/OPTIONS.html) and reading pyomo docs on how to set solver's options, assuming `solver` is handler to your solver (created with SolverFactory), I'd do it as follows:

```
solver.options['print_level'] = 12
solver.options['output_file'] = "/home/your_user/my_ipopt_log.txt"
```

This way, you have full control over where the log file will be created. As per IPOPT's documentation, the value 12 means maximum log level: *the valid range for this integer option is 0 ≤ print_level ≤ 12 and its default value is 5*